# Cannot install iOS update

Tags: ios, ipad, software-update

I have an update iOS 7.1.2 waiting which I cannot install since it tells me that I don't have enough free space. The update is 28.8 MB and I have 1.1 GB free. But the update apparently requires 1.5 GB free to install, which is absolutely ridiculous. I realize that the update itself will not use the 1.5 GB afterwards, but this just reeks of bad design. This means that on my 16 GB iPad (where I already have to economize the space) I have to waste 10% of the disk in order to be able to install updates.

So, is there a way around this issue other than deleting additional apps or data? I have already deleted more than I cared for.

Answer (score 2):

Updating through iTunes rather than OTA has a smaller storage space requirement on the device. I believe it's much closer to 1 GB, but I don't have an actual number to provide.

To update through iTunes, connect your device over USB, select it and click Update.

Comment: I figured that this might be an option (although 1 GB is still a lot). However, since I have never actually used my iPad with iTunes it wants me to sync them and transfer apps from my iPad. I will only do this as an last resort as I honestly think that iTunes is one of the worst peaces of software that has been forced upon us. I simply LOVE OTA updating and iCloud backup, and going back to iTunes (even for a moment) seems like a big step backwards.
Anyway, unless there comes a better answer I will still accept this.

Answer (score 0):

This huge hunger for disk space can also be rooted in security copies that have to be made in advance. On Windows, they are stored in the %APPDATA% “Apple Computer” directory under “MobileSync>Backup” and “iTunes>iPhone Software Updates”. Create **symbolic links** to save the needed directories on another disk drive instead. See the steps at [How to change the location where iTunes stores backups of iPhones?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/12857/how-to-change-the-location-where-itunes-stores-backups-of-iphones/75007?r=SearchResults#75007) and there the answer of @MartinPrikryl